# Spring Integration TCP server: Get the Ip address & the payload

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tcp, spring-integration

I just started using Spring-Integration, and I implemented the TCP server which just sends a "OK" message to the client. I would like to log the client IP address and the text received from the client.

I am able to successfully obtain the text sent by the client with the below configuration files, but I don't know how to obtain the IP address of the client.

Below is configuration file of the TCP server.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder />
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpServer"
                               type="server"
                               using-nio="true"
                               port="${tcpServer.port}"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="tcpGateway"
                            connection-factory="tcpServer"
                            request-channel="bytesChannel"
                            error-channel="errorChannel"/>


<int:service-activator input-channel="inputChannel" ref="myTcpService" method="processInput"/>

<bean id="myTcpService" class="MyTcpService" />

<int:transformer id="transformerBytes2String"
                 input-channel="bytesChannel"
                 output-channel="inputChannel"
                 expression="new String(payload)"/>

<int:transformer id="errorHandler"
                 input-channel="errorChannel"
                 expression="payload.failedMessage.payload + ':' + payload.cause.message"/>

<int:channel id="inputChannel" />
<int:channel id="bytesChannel"/>

</beans>
```

MyTcpService class:

```
public class MyTcpService  {
    public String processInput(String input){
       return "OK";
    }
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to get the IP address along with the payload in the "processInput" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several connection attributes are stored in the `MessageHeaders` (`TcpMessageMapper`):

```
messageBuilder
        .setHeader(IpHeaders.HOSTNAME, connection.getHostName())
        .setHeader(IpHeaders.IP_ADDRESS, connection.getHostAddress())
        .setHeader(IpHeaders.REMOTE_PORT, connection.getPort())
        .setHeader(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, connectionId);
```

Hence you can simple add one more argument to your `processInput` method to get a value from desired header:

```
public String processInput(String input, @Header(IpHeaders.IP_ADDRESS) String ip){
```

When the `input` argument without any annotations remains mapped to the `payload`.

Comment: You can also replace your `transformerBytes2String` transformer with an `<object-to-String-transformer/>`